# application.System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Projects.Models.DatabaseContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to replicate a working app and when I refactor the whole thing I'm getting

```
[Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer: Connection ID "17726168147825789580", Request ID "80000a8e-0003-f600-b63f-84710c7967bb": 
An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.System.InvalidOperationException: 
Unable to resolve service for type 'Projects.Models.DatabaseContext' while attempting to activate 'Projects.Controllers.BoxDetailController'.at 
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
Aa
```

Here's my DBcontext:

```
namespace Projects.Models
{
    public class DatabaseContext: DbContext
    {
      
            public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
            {

            }

            public DbSet<BoxDetail> BoxDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
namespace Projects.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BoxDetailController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

        public BoxDetailController(DatabaseContext context)
        { 
            _context = context;
        }

        
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<BoxDetail>>> GetBoxDetails()
        {
            return await _context.BoxDetails.ToListAsync();
        }

   
    }
}
```

and my startup class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                var resolver = options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));

            services.AddCors();
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(options =>
            options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your Startup.cs as well? That's where your services are registered. Wild guess is that you forgot to register the DB context on your DI container

Comment: @DavidGuida ok I updated the question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to ConfigureServices() :

```
services.AddMvc()
        .AddControllersAsServices();
```